# Why Dragonflydb is slower than redis in nodejs, contrarily to its benchmarks

Tags: node.js, redis

I need to instantiate a db where reads are as fast as possible, hence I thought about [DragonflyDB](https://github.com/dragonflydb/dragonfly), which claims to be much faster than redis according to their [Benchmarks](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a959500e78ab46d0becd34a87c75198bb60d7d60cd9752e37814c1728d018d69/687474703a2f2f7374617469632e647261676f6e666c7964622e696f2f7265706f2d6173736574732f6177732d7468726f7567687075742e737667). It is essentially an in-memory db, but designed in 2022, and shares almost exactly the same API as [Redis](https://redis.io/) (and Memcached) of which I need either to write/read hashes or sets.

The code I have written for such a benchmark is the following (I'm splitting it in several chunks) setting `N_ITER = 10_000`:

```
const Redis = require("ioredis")
const redis = new Redis({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 6380,
  password: "",
})

console.time("1")
const myRedisGetKeys = () =>
  Promise.all(new Array(N_ITER).fill(1).map((_, i) => redis.get(i)))

myRedisGetKeys().then(_ => {
  console.timeEnd("1")
})
```

The output is `1: 142.473ms`.

```
const Redis = require("ioredis")
const dragonfly = new Redis({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 6379,
  password: "",
})

console.time("2")
const myDragonflyGetKeys = () =>
  Promise.all(new Array(N_ITER).fill(1).map((_, i) => dragonfly.get(i)))

myDragonflyGetKeys().then(_ => {
  console.timeEnd("2")
})
```

The output is `2: 728.216ms`.

As you may notice, dragonfly seems to be 5x slower in reading than Redis. What is wrong with my approach?

P.S. If needed, I could provide the same results using Python code, where redis performs faster but only by a 20% factor.

Comment: Did you test with 64 vCPU's and 512GB of RAM? And I doubt that 10K keys will provide sufficiently relevant data.

Comment: My laptop has 12 vCPUs and 20GB of RAM. With 1mln reads I get 1 minute in DragonflyDB and 5 seconds in Redis. I wouldn't expect so much difference, even though I am aware the environment is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to test / benchmark?

Dragonfly is designed for high workloads, specifically when serving multiple requests in parallel (usually from multiple clients).

I believe that your benchmark sends a bunch of data before Redis / Dragonfly even gets to respond, which results in pipelining, in which case Redis and Dragonfly will have similar performance, and indeed on my attempt to run this code I get similar numbers.

If your production workload is going to be similar (a single connection issuing many `get` operations and then disconnecting), you may not necessarily enjoy the benefits of Dragonfly.

If your production workload is different (like sending traffic across all hours, with some fluctuations between low- and high-traffic), then I suggest you modify your benchmark to match that, or just use existing benchmark tools (like Redis' [memtier](https://www.google.com/search?q=redis+memtier&oq=redis+memtier&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB4yBggCEEUYQNIBCDU4NDdqMGoxqAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))